# No such User exists (Firebase orderByChild equalTo)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new at this and I'm having trouble logging in. It always gives a warning that 'No such user exists' even if the username is in Firebase Realtime Database.

Here's my code:

```java
 private void isUser() {

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        final String userEnteredUsername = username.getText().toString().trim();
        final String userEnteredPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userEnteredUsername);

        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //get the data

                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    username.setError(null);

                    String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("information").child("password").getValue(String.class);

                    if(passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)){

                        password.setError(null);

                        String nameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("information").child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                        String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("information").child("username").getValue(String.class);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        password.setError("Wrong Password");
                        password.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    username.setError("No such User exist");
                    username.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I don't have any idea where is the error. But I think, maybe, I have a mistake in orderByChild("username").

And my database is like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "John" : {
      "information" : {
        "email" : "johnmohammad@gmail.com",
        "fullname" : "John Mohammad",
        "mobileNumber" : "096***71**4",
        "password" : "john123",
        "username" : "John"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks. I already edit it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether a particular user exists in your database, you have two options. The first one would be to use a reference that points exactly to the user name under the "users" node as shown in the following lines of code:

```
String name = "John";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
DatabaseReference nameRef = usersRef.child(name);
nameRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String username = snapshot.child("information").child("username").getValue(String.class);
            String password = snapshot.child("information").child("password").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", username + "/" + password);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can use the following query if the username from the information node can be different than the key:

```
Query queryByName = usersRef.orderByChild("information/username").equalTo(name);
queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String username = ds.child("information").child("username").getValue(String.class);
                String password = ds.child("information").child("password").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", username + "/" + password);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In both cases the result in the logcat will be:

```
John/john123
```

Besides that, in order to make it work, don't forget to add ".indexOn": "information/username", for path "/users", to the rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "information/username",
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }      
  }
}
```

If you intend to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), otherwise:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "information/username",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }      
  }
}
```